# How can I log a Django user into WooCommerce without prompting?

Tags: django, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, single-sign-on

My workflow takes the user from a Django web application to a WooCommerce store. For example, they fill in `example.com/register` and are taken to `store.com/checkout`.

Both applications are backed by the same LDAP database, so at the moment I prompt the user to enter their credentials a second time.

This is functional, but not the greatest UX. How can I transport them from the Django to store domain *and* sign them into the store, without user intervention?

(Because the domains are different and I expect third-party cookies to be disabled, I obviously can't generate a cookie for the store domain while still in the Django domain.)